# User mysql and sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session, credentials

Does the credentials used for the mysql connection affect in any way the session variables or such?

I mean, if my database in page 1 is accessed with a certain username/password and in the following one, I access the same database with different credentials, does that have any side effect that could break something?

Comment: What is page 1? I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: I think he means it as an arbitrary page on his site.

Comment: A checkout process for example. Is it a requirement that all database connections are done with the same credentials for some reason? Or can I switch users between connections if I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding the question properly:

When storing your sessions in mysql instead of on the filesystem, The mysql username / password used to connect to the mysql database needs insert and select privileges to the table.  If you have multiple mysql users who have access, the data that is inserted / selected does not have any context as long as both mysql users have access to the table.

That being said:

You should be using the same user / password to connect to mysql from php.  It will work if you use different accounts (if they have privileges), but it has no context on the user's session data and might just end up giving you a headache.

Comment: It's just a temporary solution for a client. The server he uses has a `max_question` mysql limit that targets users. So until he gets that limit up, I'm tricking the database by using two users alternatively.